# Discord.Net - Check if User has ManageServer permission

Tags: c#, discord.net

Trying to check if a User has the ManageServer Permission. I've already got the DiscordClientId & DiscordGuildId and the below is designed to get the current users permissions and from there I can specify the permission I'm looking for, but I can't figure it out

```
var user = userClientId;
var server = guildId;
var userServerPermissions = server.GetPermissions(user);
```

EDIT: I'm using a HttpWebRequest to get the DiscordClientId and GuildId's for the user when they login via Oauth2, then splitting out the various data I need to get the Id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you look into using a library for doing this. The one I've always used is [Discord.NET](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net#discordnet), the library you mentioned on your question with the discord.net tag. Another C# discord library I'm aware of is DSharpPlus but I've never tried it.

For Discord.NET I suggest using the nightly/preview versions because they incorporate the recent Discord intents change. Use them by adding `https://www.myget.org/F/discord-net/api/v3/index.json` to your Nuget package sources.

A library handles everything nicely for you, meaning that you never need to directly send requests to or receive requests from Discord. Read the Discord.NET getting started guide [here](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/introduction/intro.html).

Here's code from Discord.NET which will determine if some user in some guild has the ManageServer permission:

```cs
public bool HasManageServerPermission(SocketGuildUser user)
{
    return user.GuildPermissions.ManageGuild;
}
```